# Why is Google Drive (web) constantly asking me to allow it to use 1.2 GB of storage on my Mac?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, mac, safari

For the past couple of days every time I view folders in my organization's Google Drive account I get the following popup message:

> Do you want to allow “https://drive.google.com” to use up to 1.2 GB of storage on your Mac?

I can't find any information online regarding this type of popup message asking for local storage which is odd. So I can't determine if it is a Google setting or a Mac/Safari setting let alone why it is requesting 1.2 GB storage. Especially since it also says I'm only using 394 MB of storage.

I want to understand why it is asking this question so I can make an informed decision about accepting or rejecting the request. And make it stop regenerating the popup every time I load a page on Google Drive.

Any info is greatly appreciated!

Edit to add:

I'm in the decision-making process for my org acquiring G Suite and need to understand if it is caching org files on personal devices, and if so how they are protected on personal devices we don't control.

Comment: Not sure what it is but seems like more people are getting it https://support.google.com/drive/thread/41259048?hl=en and https://support.google.com/drive/thread/34417678?hl=en

Comment: It seems to be related to https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/give-more-space-to-website-databases-sfri20879/13.0/mac/10.15 (not a new thing), but I don't know why Drive started asking this from you and if it is actually needed. Maybe you have some files setup to Allow Offline Access

Comment: It sounds to me like Google wants to improve your access to your files on your Google web app, by storing them offline.

Comment: Try using other web browsers, specially Google Chrome, as some Google apps features only work with it.

Comment: Regarding storing files on personal machines, I was surprised that you wouldn't want people to make use of the sync feature, since IMO that's the main point to Google Drive, but I see that [sync can be disabled in G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7496409).

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, continually being asked if 1.7 GB of hard drive space could be utilized.  For what I did not know.  And this was not Google Drive; just regular internet use.  It turned out my cache of cookies in Safari was crowded (like 3700 websites).  I cleared the cache and the problem went away.

Answer (score -2):

I'm looking for a solution to this issue. For me it started when I was uploading files into google drive. I dragged files in and when it asked me if I wanted to let google use the memory I clicked yes. I was checking if the files made it in already and since I  didn't see progress I dragged the files in again. I soon noticed that the 1st set up files were slowly being uploaded into the drive so when It asked me if I wanted to allow google to use that memory I always click "no" since I don't want duplicate files. Now every time I open google drive it asks me the same question. I'm trying to figure out how to get it to stop asking that.